# Confirmation pop up when user leaves page vs closes browser/tab

Tags: angular, browser, candeactivate

currently when the user leaves the page I use the `beforeunload` event to show the default browser popup.

But I don't want this popup when the user navigates to another page or so on. I have a `canDeactivate` guard with a custom popup and a custom confirmation message to do that.

I want the default browser popup only when the user tries to close the browser/tab.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

may you can use ngx-page-visibility,
I am not sure if it will serve exactly your needs, check it first

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend try this it will help you for you [open it](https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d)